# SKProduct Swift - Where does the information come from?

Tags: swift, xcode, skproduct

does the "SKProductsRequest" for in-app purchases go to the internet (App Store) and collect the information or does it get the information of the product price and so on directly from the installed app on the device? Especially the following code in viewDidLoad()

```
requestIAP = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set([inAppIdentifierForProVersion]))
requestIAP.delegate = self
requestIAP.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Apple documentation for the start() function it does launch a network request to the app store.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skrequest

But it seems that the response is stored locally as I can force close my app. Go to plane mode and display the price items again when I relaunch my app.

Answer (score 0):

Thx, but after some minutes it will "lose" the stored information, so you need to do the request again.

Comment: Probably yes, I think it is to be sure that the displayed info about the product is always up to date. You don't want to display a product that is no more available or with an outdated price. In any case as all transactions will be validated by the App Store there will be a need for network calls at some points.